# IoT Edge AMQP traffic overhead

Tags: traffic, azure-iot-edge

For the past few days I've been struggling to analyze the traffic that an IoT Edge device generates when transmitting data to IoT Hub.

The metrics in the hub fall in line perfectly with my expectation of around 120KB per hour, which is roughly the size of the messages I`m sending with the module client.

But when I monitor the network traffic of the device the result is 20MB sent and around 10 MB received, for a total of over 30MB per hour for AMQPS which is a huge difference.

Has anyone encountered this and is there some way to find out the reason for the discrepancy in the data.

Comment: Currently if you switch to MQTT as a transport protocol of the IoT Edge modules the traffic behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in IoT Edge runtime and was resolved with version 1.0.2 more info can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/182)

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub provides several [metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-metrics#iot-hub-metrics-and-how-to-use-them) to give you an overview of the health of your hub and the total number of connected devices. In your mentions, the metric only included d2c messages. The communication between the client and service includes not only d2c messeage protocol but also other protocols.

Azure IoT Edge bridges the traffic to IoT Hub over AMQP 1.0. It plugs in components for specialized processing such as custom authentication, message transformations, compression/decompression, or encryption/decryption of traffic between the devices and IoT Hub. 
The Azure IoT protocol gateway and MQTT/AMQP implementation are provided in an open-source software project.You can refer to [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Amqp](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Amqp).

Comment: I`m aware that there is the overhead of the AMQP and other communication going on with the cloud. What I can't understand is if we've made a mistake in our implementation or the overhead is from the underlaying implementation of the iotEdge, which to be frank if it's generating traffic in the range of tens of MB per hour is something that I don't expect of a service that is supposed to work over a cellular connection and transmit data constantly

Comment: @DobrinTinchev, how did you monitor the network traffic? Why are you sure the 20M sent is only from edge over AMQPS? I think you can stop the edge and then monitor the network again, check if there are other communications cause the data traffic.

Comment: The traffic was only over amqps. It was acknowledged by the product team of IoT edge as a bug and there is a PR that should fix the issue. You can track in to GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/182)